# Пользовательский класс string

Tags: c++

Зависает программа после ввода строки.Подскажите в чем ошибка?

```
#include<iostream>

#include <cstring>

class MyString
{
    private:
        size_t length;
        char *str;

    public:
        MyString ();
        MyString (const char *c);
        MyString (const MyString& t);
        ~MyString ();

        MyString& operator= (const MyString& t);
        MyString& operator= (const char *c);
        MyString operator+ (const MyString& t) const;
        MyString& operator+= (const MyString& t);
        char& operator[] (size_t i);
        const char& operator[] (size_t i) const;

        char& at (size_t i);
        const char& at (size_t i) const;
        void get_input (std::istream& in);
        size_t get_length () const;
        void from_c_str (const char *other);

        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const MyString& t);
        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, MyString& t);
        friend bool operator== (const MyString& t, char *c);
        friend bool operator== (const MyString& t, const MyString& t1);
        friend bool operator!= (const MyString& t, char *c);
        friend bool operator!= (const MyString& t, const MyString& t1);
};

MyString::MyString ()
{
    length = 1;
    str = '\0';
}

MyString::MyString (const char *c)
{
    from_c_str (c);
}

MyString::MyString (const MyString& t)
{
    from_c_str (t.str);
}

MyString::~MyString ()
{
    delete[] str;
}

MyString& MyString::operator= (const MyString& t)
{
    from_c_str (t.str);

    return *this;
}

MyString& MyString::operator= (const char *c)
{
    from_c_str (c);

    return *this;
}

MyString MyString::operator+ (const MyString& t) const
{
    return (MyString(str) += t.str);
}








bool operator== (const MyString& t, char *c)
{
    return (strcmp(t.str, c) == 0);
}

bool operator== (const MyString& t, const MyString& t1)
{
    return (strcmp(t.str, t1.str) == 0);
}

bool operator!= (const MyString& t, char *c)
{
    return !(operator== (t, c));
}

bool operator!= (const MyString& t, const MyString& t1)
{
    return !(operator== (t, t1.str));
}

MyString& MyString::operator+= (const MyString& t)
{
    length = strlen (str) + strlen (t.str) + 1;
    char *newStr = new char[length];
    strcpy (newStr, str);
    strcat (newStr, t.str);
    strcpy (str, newStr);
    str[length-1] = '\0';
    delete[] newStr;

    return *this;
}

char& MyString::operator[] (size_t i)
{
    return str[i];
}

const char& MyString::operator[] (size_t i) const
{
    return str[i];
}

void MyString::get_input (std::istream& in)
{
    while (true)
    {
        char c = in.get ();

        if (c == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }

        if (length == 0)
        {
            length = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            ++length;
        }

        char* newStr = new char[length];
        if (str != NULL)
        {
            strcpy (newStr, str);
        }
        newStr[length-2] = c;
        newStr[length-1] = '\0';

        delete[] str;

        str = newStr;
    }
}

size_t MyString::get_length () const
{
    return (length - 1);
}

void MyString::from_c_str (const char *c)
{
    length = strlen (c) + 1;
    str = new char[length];
    strcpy (str, c);
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const MyString& t)
{
    out << t.str;
    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, MyString& t)
{
    t.get_input (in);
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    MyString st;
    MyString zt;
    MyString tt;
    cin >> st;
    cout << st<<endl;
    cin >> zt;
    cout <<zt<<endl;

    tt = st += zt;
    cout << tt;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не виснет: https://ideone.com/YGeW6T

Answer (score 1):

В конструкторе

```
MyString::MyString ()
{
    length = 1;
    str = '\0';
}
```

переменная **str** указывает на константную область кода, а в коде везде вы удаляете **str** последствия непредсказуемые. Сначала нужно выделять память и записывать туда нулевой байт. Ошибка в сложении двух строк :

```
MyString& MyString::operator+= (const MyString& t)
{
    length = strlen (str) + strlen (t.str) + 1;
    char *newStr = new char[length];
    strcpy (newStr, str);
    strcat (newStr, t.str);
    strcpy (str, newStr);
    str[length-1] = '\0';
    delete[] newStr;

    return *this;
}
```

Новая строка **newStr** уже собрана, а вы копируете большую строку в маленькую часть памяти **str**. Можно сделать это так :

```
delete[] str;
str = newStr;
```

Comment: "переменная str указывает на константную область кода" - что это значит? О какой "константную области кода" идет речь? После `str = '\0'` (если компилятор это разрешит) указатель `str` будет просто null.

Comment: **str='\0'** не заметил, думал что строчка. Код тяжело читать, написали-бы **NULL**.

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   MyString::MyString ()
   {
     length = 1;
     str = '\0';
   }
   ```

   Начиная с C++11 `str = '\0'` уже запрещено. Да и даже до С++11 такая запись хоть и являлась корректной, но все равно была сбивающей с толку. Это эквивалентно `str = nullptr`. Почему при этом делается `length = 1` - не ясно. Откуда взялось
   `1`?
2. ```
   MyString& MyString::operator+= (const MyString& t)
   {
     length = strlen (str) + strlen (t.str) + 1;
     char *newStr = new char[length];
     strcpy (newStr, str);
     strcat (newStr, t.str);
     strcpy (str, newStr);
     str[length-1] = '\0';
     delete[] newStr;

     return *this;
   }
   ```

   Тут уже написана какая-то чушь. Результат правильно формируется в `newStr`, но потом зачем-то тупо копируется в `str` при помощи `strcpy (str, newStr)` (!). Это как это? В `str` не хватит места для всей `newStr`. Вылет за пределы выделенной памяти, поведение не определено.
3. ```
   MyString& MyString::operator= (const MyString& t)
   {
     from_c_str (t.str);

     return *this;
   }

   MyString& MyString::operator= (const char *c)
   {
     from_c_str (c);

     return *this;
   }
   ```

   В результате такого "присваивания" старое содержимое строки становится утечкой памяти. Оператор присваивания обязан освобождать старое содержимое строки.
4. Оператор `+=` написан только в одной форме

   ```
   MyString MyString::operator+ (const MyString& t) const
   ```

   но при этом используется в коде со вторым операндом типа `char *`. Это работает благодарая конструктору конверсии

   ```
   MyString::MyString (const char *c)
   ```

   Но почему тогда для всех остальных операторов реализовано две отдельных версии? одна для `MyString`, другая для `const char *c`? Где логика? И почему в реализации

   ```
   MyString MyString::operator+ (const MyString& t) const
   {
     return (MyString(str) += t.str);
   }
   ```

   делается вызов `+=` именно с использованием конструктора конверсии, когда можно было запросто обойтись без него

   ```
   MyString MyString::operator+ (const MyString& t) const
   {
     return MyString(*this) += t;
   }
   ```

   ?